# Dataset where svm performance is significantly different from random forest

Tags: dataset, random-forest, svm

Is there a specific dataset where svm performs significantly better or worse than random forest?

I know that the performance could depend on the dataset but is there a specific dataset?

Comment: You believe that in general both have same performance. So you are looking for exceptional scenarios. Did I get the question right?

Answer (score 1):

Geographical datasets (e.g. when predicting population density from the built environment characteristics in my case) are, at least from my experience, one of the cases where SVM performs consistently worse than random forests. Although I have not investigated the issue in detail, it seems that random forests are more resistant to high amounts of noise and can learn to apply different rulesets in different regions or environments, something which SVM (SVR) fails to do.